# Roll up site micro feeds to home page

Tags: 2013

How do i roll up microfeeds to site home page using the CSWP?

I am struggling to roll up a list of microfeeds from my intranet to the homepage.

Comment: How about using the OOTB "Site Feed" Web-part under Social Collaboration ?

Comment: Hi, thats what im using but i have over 100 sites with site feeds and i need to roll them all up onto 1 news page